# Polygon Shape Similarity using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-statistics

Does anybody know if there is a way to statistical calculate the similarity of two polygons using PostGIS?

[image]

I want to know how similar is the polygon (red outline) with the polygon (black outline).

Comment: Questions asking for "any ideas?" without specifying the particular software you have tried, are stuck on and wish to ask about are too broad. The PostGIS answer now makes this a PostGIS Q&A so if you wish to know about another particular question then can you ask a new question, please?

Comment: I have tried to develop my own similarity index using intersection and symmetrical difference in QGIS. Unfortunately i havent succeed. I was thinking, perhaps there is already a tool to assess the similarity. I havent tried this in postgis.

Comment: If you want to pursue the same thing using QGIS then please ask that as a new question for QGIS.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the PostGIS function - ST_HausdorffDistance

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html

This is a measure of how similar or dissimilar two shapes are.